# Amplitude of a transfer function

Tags: complex, algebraic-manipulation

I'm looking to calculate the amplitude of a transfer function which is defined in a symbolic way :

```
T=(1 + 2 I r λ)/(1 - r^2 + 2 I r λ)
```

I try this, i doesn't work

```
Assuming[{λ > 0, r > 0}, Simplify[Abs[TAdimen]]] r λ)
```

Do you have ideas so as to calculate the amplitude of a transfer function in a symbolic manner?

Comment: You might be interested in `ComplexExpand[]`.